# update ejs page variables once the variables change in server side without refreshing

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I want to make a dynamic page, with node server and EJS. And i have some variables  in server side that change. And I am wondering is it possible to update the content of the page(those variable), once any of the variables in server changes. Without refreshing.

I read some where that, with Ajax and sending a get request, I can get updated data. But as it is not simultaneous, I like to know, is it possible to make this happen simultaneously?

For simplicity, I write a very simple code. With an integer variable that increases in the server side. and a simple "index.ejs" to show that variable in the web. but i dont know how to make that content dynamic as that variable changes in the server side.
thanks in advance.

**Server side : app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require('ejs');

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen(3000 , function(){
    console.log("Server on port 3000");
});

var i=0;

setInterval(function(){
    i++;
} , 1000);

app.get("/" , function(req , res){
    res.render("index" , {var : i} );
});
```

**Client Side : index.ejs**

```
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>My Variable is <span><%= var %></span></p>            

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It depends on how often the variable changes and if you need to know it immediately. If so then use websockets. Create a connection back to server when the page loads. Then whenever the variable changes you can send it to the client from the server.

Comment: it is completely random that variables change.

Comment: i am not familiar with websockets, but thank you, i will search about it.